# How to get the browser Cookies using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cookies, cross-domain

I want to get the Browser cookies using JavaScript.I tried the below code , but i am not getting the cross domain cookies.

Here is the code:

```
function get_cookies_array() {
  var cookies = {};
  if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
    var split = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
      var name_value = split[i].split("=");
      name_value[0] = name_value[0].replace(/^ /, '');
      cookies[decodeURIComponent(name_value[0])] = decodeURIComponent(name_value[1]);
    }
  }
  return cookies;
}
var cookies = get_cookies_array();
for (var name in cookies) {
  document.write(name + " : " + cookies[name] + "<br />");
}
```

Does anybody solve this.

Comment: You cannot get the cookies that you have from another domain, if that's your question. Not possible.

Comment: Is there any possibities to get those cookies using some other way?
@nicovank

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342140/cross-domain-cookies refer thos link

Comment: Say WebApp1 and WebApp 2. I do have access to WebApp 1 and I do not have access  for WebApp 2 . But I need to read the cookies of WebApp2. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most situations, you cannot read cross domain cookies, for security reasons.

Each cookie has a domain of definition, and your browser reads those to decide which cookies you can read according to which domain you're on.

If you have control of both domains, you can modify cookie settings on domain B to allow them to be read by domain A, or code a cookie getter to get the values. Be creative!